# ML always returns 0

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

I am trying to implement **ML** and here is an example:

- 3 variable values
- one result value depending on other values

Test data are entered the same so it should return the same values

**Always returns 0 for countConnectors.CountConnectors**

Did I forget something?

Code:

```
public class Balcony
{
    public float A { get; set; }
    public float L { get; set; }
    public float HB { get; set; }
    public float CountConnectors { get; set; }
}

public class PredictionConnectors
{
    [ColumnName("Count")]
    public float CountConnectors { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MLContext mlContext = new MLContext();

    Balcony[] balconyData = {
               new Balcony() { A = 500F, L = 180F, HB = 20F, CountConnectors = 10F },
               new Balcony() { A = 500F, L = 180F, HB = 20F, CountConnectors = 10F },
               new Balcony() { A = 500F, L = 180F, HB = 20F, CountConnectors = 10F },
               new Balcony() { A = 500F, L = 180F, HB = 20F, CountConnectors = 10F },
               new Balcony() { A = 500F, L = 180F, HB = 20F, CountConnectors = 10F },
               new Balcony() { A = 500F, L = 180F, HB = 20F, CountConnectors = 10F },
               new Balcony() { A = 500F, L = 180F, HB = 20F, CountConnectors = 10F },
               new Balcony() { A = 500F, L = 180F, HB = 20F, CountConnectors = 10F },
               new Balcony() { A = 500F, L = 180F, HB = 20F, CountConnectors = 10F },
            };

    IDataView trainingData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(balconyData);

    var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "A", "L", "HB")
        .Append(mlContext.Regression.Trainers.Sdca(labelColumnName: "CountConnectors", maximumNumberOfIterations: 100));

    var model = pipeline.Fit(trainingData);

    var balcony = new Balcony() { A = 500F, L = 180F, HB = 20F };
    var countConnectors = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<Balcony, PredictionConnectors>(model).Predict(balcony);

    Console.WriteLine($"Predicted A: {balcony.A}, L: {balcony.L}, HB: {balcony.HB} connectors= {countConnectors.CountConnectors} szt.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Prediction class `PredictionConnectors` output property must be decorated with `ColumnName("Score")` attribute.

```
public class PredictionConnectors
{
    [ColumnName("Score")]
    public float CountConnectors { get; set; }
}
```